# How to gather values into array by keys?

Tags: text-processing, json, jq

Given input in entries format, possibly with duplicated keys, e.g.

```json
[
  {"key": "a", "value": 0},
  {"key": "a", "value": 1},
  {"key": "a", "value": 2},
  {"key": "b", "value": 3},
  {"key": "b", "value": 4},
  {"key": "b", "value": 5}
]
```

I want to produce

```json
{"a": [0, 1, 2], "b": [3, 4, 5]}
```

Namely, to gather all values with the same key in an array for each unique key.

How can I do this in `jq`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `reduce()` in `jq` to gradually build up the resulting object by adding the given `value` values to the keys given by the `key` values:

```bash
$ jq -c 'reduce .[] as $a ({}; .[$a.key] += [$a.value])' file
{"a":[0,1,2],"b":[3,4,5]}
```

The `reduce()` acts like a sort of loop that, in this case, iterates over `.[]`, i.e. all the objects in your top-level array.  For each object, `$a`, the value `$a.value` is added to the result object (which is initially the empty `{}` object) under the key `$a.key`.

---

An additional tip for people who like playing with `jq`: By using `debug`, you can look at the data at any point in your expression when it's running.  Here I'm investigating the state of the accumulator object after each iteration in the `reduce()` loop:

```bash
$ jq -c 'reduce .[] as $a ({}; .[$a.key] += [$a.value] | debug)' file
["DEBUG:",{"a":[0]}]
["DEBUG:",{"a":[0,1]}]
["DEBUG:",{"a":[0,1,2]}]
["DEBUG:",{"a":[0,1,2],"b":[3]}]
["DEBUG:",{"a":[0,1,2],"b":[3,4]}]
["DEBUG:",{"a":[0,1,2],"b":[3,4,5]}]
{"a":[0,1,2],"b":[3,4,5]}
```

And here I'm investigating the values that are assigned to `$a` in each iteration:

```bash
$ jq -c 'reduce (.[]|debug) as $a ({}; .[$a.key] += [$a.value])' file
["DEBUG:",{"key":"a","value":0}]
["DEBUG:",{"key":"a","value":1}]
["DEBUG:",{"key":"a","value":2}]
["DEBUG:",{"key":"b","value":3}]
["DEBUG:",{"key":"b","value":4}]
["DEBUG:",{"key":"b","value":5}]
{"a":[0,1,2],"b":[3,4,5]}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `group_by` , `map` and `from_entries`

```
jq 'group_by(.key) | map({key: .[0].key, value: [.[].value]}) | from_entries' data.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

You need to use a JSON parser:

```perl
~$ raku -MJSON::Tiny -e 'my @json = from-json($_).list given slurp;  \
         my %accum.push: .<key> => .<value>.map(*.Num).Slip for @json>>.split(", ");  \
         .say for to-json(%accum.sort);'  file
```

Sample Input:

```perl
[
  {"key": "a", "value": 0},
  {"key": "a", "value": 1},
  {"key": "a", "value": 2},
  {"key": "b", "value": 3},
  {"key": "b", "value": 4},
  {"key": "b", "value": 5}
]
```

Sample Output (values have been `Num`-ified and `Slip`ped, i.e. flattened):

```json
[ { "a" : [ 0, 1, 2 ] }, { "b" : [ 3, 4, 5 ] } ]
```

The final code adds a call to `to-json()` at the end. To figure out what's going on in the intermediate steps, it's probably easiest to show you the output of each individual data structure. Printing the `@json` array with `.say for @json;` returns the following:

```perl
{key => a, value => 0}
{key => a, value => 1}
{key => a, value => 2}
{key => b, value => 3}
{key => b, value => 4}
{key => b, value => 5}
```

Generating an `%accum` hash with only  `.<key> => .<value>` (in other words, without `.map(*.Num).Slip`) returns the following via a call to `.say for %accum.sort;`:

```perl
[ { "a" : [ [ "0" ], [ "1" ], [ "2" ] ] }, { "b" : [ [ "3" ], [ "4" ], [ "5" ] ] } ]
```

Note, you can do various manipulations of the values with function calls like `Num`, `Int`, etc., and you can "flatten" with a call to `Slip` as in the code posted at top.

Raku's `JSON::Tiny` module will stringify values by default, and if you want those stringified values as a single list (instead of sub-lists), you `Slip` them together.

Below, stringified values `Slip`ped together:

```perl
~$ raku -MJSON::Tiny -e 'my @json = from-json($_).list given slurp;  \
         my %accum.push: .<key> => .<value>.Slip for @json>>.split(", ");  \  
        .say for to-json(%accum.sort);'  file
[ { "a" : [ "0", "1", "2" ] }, { "b" : [ "3", "4", "5" ] } ]
```

So a lot of options here for data output, the simplest being taking the code at the top and removing the final `to-json()` call, to see Raku's "pairs" representation of the `%accum` hash:

```
a => [0 1 2]
b => [3 4 5]
```

https://raku.land/cpan:MORITZ/JSON::Tiny
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

If you already know a programming language, that's a easy option rather than having to use the very specific `jq` language. With `perl`:

```
$ perl -MJSON -l -0777 -ne '
    for (@{decode_json$_}) {push @{$out->{$_->{key}}}, $_->{value}}
    print encode_json $out' your-file.json
{"a":[0,1,2],"b":[3,4,5]}
```